# How to send select data from the child component to App component by select option, React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, react-router, react-props

I'd like to change the status and priority data in the app component by selecting the option in the child component, clicking on submit data and pass replace the Task main array data - status and priority with the new selected. I'm expecting to change the data by clicking the submit button. I was trying to form the object editedTask in the handleSaveTask function and pass the changed values to the App.js component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-24-04-vp0v8m?file=/src/components/TaskComponent.js

```js
// Child component

import React from "react";
import { useParams, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const TaskComponent = ({ Tasks, status, setStatus, priority, setPriority }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const { id } = useParams();

  const task = Tasks.find((task) => String(task.id) === id);

  const handleSaveTask = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let editedTask = {
      status: status,
      priority: priority
    };
    history.push("/taskslist");
  };

  if (!task) {
    return <div>No Task</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div>
        <h3>{task.title}</h3>
        <h4>{task.author_name}</h4>
        <p>{task.description}</p>
        <form onSubmit={handleSaveTask}>
          <label>Status</label>
          <select value={status} onChange={(e) => setStatus(e.target.value)}>
            <option value="0">In queue</option>
            <option value="1">In progress</option>
            <option value="2">Completed</option>
          </select>
          <select
            value={priority}
            onChange={(e) => setPriority(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="0">Low</option>
            <option value="1">Medium</option>
            <option value="2">High</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TaskComponent;

// App component

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Taskslist from "./components/Taskslist";
import TaskComponent from "./components/TaskComponent";

const Tasks = [
  {
    id: "001",
    status: 0,
    priority: 2,
    title: "Develop website homepage",
    description:
      "Create a visually appealing and responsive homepage for the website",
    schedule: {
      creation_time: "2021-07-23T10:00:00"
    },
    author_name: "John Smith"
  },
  {
    id: "002",
    status: 1,
    priority: 1,
    title: "Implement user authentication",
    description: "Add user authentication feature to the website",
    schedule: {
      creation_time: "2021-07-24T14:30:00"
    },
    author_name: "Sarah Lee"
  },
];


function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Tasks);
  // const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  // const [priority, setPriority] = useState(false);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/taskslist">
            <Taskslist Tasks={tasks} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/task/:id">
            <TaskComponent Tasks={tasks} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```